# Cross-platform microsecond precise timestamp

Tags: c++, c

I am writing a logging class which should provide the current date and time at a microsecond precision level. I do not want to format all log messages directly using snprintf (so they can be filtered efficiently) but rather have a struct like this:

```
struct log_record {
    timestamp_t time;
    uint32_t    msg_len;
    ...
}
```

This should be able to be shared with other machines (using tcp, for example) which may have another cpu, os (linux and windows), etc. Is there an existing timestamp format / library (maybe in some database system?) that would work out for my requirements?

Comment: You realize that synchronizing multiple machine's clocks to microsecond-level is not trivial, right? In other words, even if you can get a local timestamp with that precision (which you can), you can't just assume that they are *correct* with respect to global time. [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) achieves on the order of a few miliseconds.

Comment: Yes, I don't need them to be super correct wrt. global time. But I want to have the possibility to have a server which does all the heavy part of logging (formatting the messages, filtering them by certain criteria, check for logical consistency, storing them to files, ...) for all individual clients. For this purpose I need to have a cross-platform timestamp data format / structure.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794612/getting-time-point-with-microseconds-precision/29795430)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve microsecond *granularity* on some platforms, but you won't get microsecond *precision*, since the system clock is most certainly not that accurate.  Expect offsets of seconds or even minutes on typical desktop machines, down to milliseconds on machines that are carefully synchronised using NTP.

On all Unix systems known to me (including Linux), good old `gettimeofday` yields a granularity somewhere between 10ms and 1µs, depending on the OS and the hardware:

```
rc = gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
```

On most Linux platforms, `clock_gettime` gives somewhat better granularity, down to hundreds of nanoseconds:

```
rc = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
```

On Windows, you'll want to use the [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724397.aspx) function, the results of which you can then convert to something useful using the [`FileTimeToSystemTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724280.aspx) function.  However, this will only get you a granularity of a few dozen milliseconds, unless you play dirty tricks with performance counters.

Comment: Windows 8 added [GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh706895(v=vs.85).aspx) which does the dirty tricks for you. Recommended reading for Windows high resolution time is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You are right, but those functions return different data types, a struct timeval (which consists of two long ints - but long int may differ between platforms) and a FILETIME struct. On top of that, there is the 2038 year problem. What I need is a timestamp of fixed width/format that I can create and parse on 32 and 64 bit ARM, Intel, AMD cpus and linux and windows systems with different compilers. Or some conversion library that will do the trick.

Comment: My post and the comment by Mike Vine give you everything you need in order to roll your own.  Once you've written and debugged such a snippet, feel free to edit your question to point at it.